How to map a nested class by CsvHelper?
class A
{
    public C MyC;
    public int OtherStuff;
}

class B
{
    public C MyC1;
    public C MyC2;
}

class C
{
    public int WeirdInt;
    public string WeirdString;
}

I want to create a rule for C to map. When I try to convert List<A> or List<B> to csv, it use this rule to map C.
The CSV header of List<A> may look like this:
MyC_WeirdInt, MyC_WeirdString, OtherStuff

The CSV header of List<B> may look like this:
MyC1_WeirdInt, MyC1_WeirdString,MyC2\_(repeat)

Like this can complete my wish, but I don't want to write the same code 3 times:
class AMap : ClassMap<A>
{
    public AMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.MyC.WeirdInt).Name("MyC_WeirdInt");
        Map(m => m.MyC.WeirdString).Name("MyC_WeirdString");
        Map(m => m.OtherStuff);
    }
}

class BMap : ClassMap<B>
{
    public BMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.MyC1.WeirdInt).Name("MyC1_WeirdInt");
        Map(m => m.MyC1.WeirdString).Name("MyC1_WeirdString");
        Map(m => m.MyC2.WeirdInt).Name("MyC2_WeirdInt");
        Map(m => m.MyC2.WeirdString).Name("MyC2_WeirdString");
    }
}


don't you just need a mapping for class C as well. like class c : ClassMap<C>?

There are ways to customize how the headers are written. It requires some extra coding, but none approach (I will show 2) is difficult.
Here's your corrected setup with sample autogenerated data:
public class A
{
    public C MyC { get; set; } = new C(); // Initialized with a new C object
    public int OtherStuff { get; set; } = 42; // Example value for integer
}

public class B
{
    public C MyC1 { get; set; } = new C(); // Initialized with a new C object
    public C MyC2 { get; set; } = new C(); // Another C object for second property
}

public class C
{
    public int WeirdInt { get; set; } = 99; // Example value for integer
    public string WeirdString { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); // Random string (GUID)
}

And here are two ways of writing CSV - one without modifying header names, and the other with appending desired prefix (such as MyC1_):
const string export_path_a = "test-a.csv";
const string export_path_b = "test-b.csv";

var aList = new List<A>();
aList.Add(new A());
aList.Add(new A());
aList.Add(new A());

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(export_path_a))
{
    using (CsvWriter csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        // This will write headers taking names from property names
        // but without prefixes.
        csv.WriteHeader(typeof(C));
        csv.WriteHeader(typeof(A));
        csv.NextRecord();
        foreach (var item in aList)
        {
            csv.WriteRecord(item.MyC);
            csv.WriteRecord(item);
            csv.NextRecord();
        }
    }
}

var bList = new List<B>();
bList.Add(new B());
bList.Add(new B());
bList.Add(new B());

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(export_path_b))
{
    using (CsvWriter csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        // Here we need to manually iterate over the props we want to save.
        // This will write header names with prefixes.
        foreach (var cProp in typeof(C).GetProperties())
            csv.WriteField("MyC1_" + cProp.Name);

        foreach (var cProp in typeof(C).GetProperties())
            csv.WriteField("MyC2_" + cProp.Name);

        csv.NextRecord();
        foreach (var item in bList)
        {
            csv.WriteRecord(item.MyC1);
            csv.WriteRecord(item.MyC2);
            csv.NextRecord();
        }
    }
}

Related question: Write CSV from Nested anonymous object

You can use the References<TClassMap>() method of ClassMap<TClass> to pull in a pre-existing class map for a field or property:

 /// Maps a member to another class map. When this is used, accessing a property through
 /// sub-property mapping later won't work. You can only use one or the other. When using
 /// this, ConvertUsing will also not work.
 /// </summary>
 /// <typeparam name="TClassMap">The type of the class map.</typeparam>
 /// <param name="expression">The expression.</param>
 /// <param name="constructorArgs">Constructor arguments used to create the reference map.</param>
 /// <returns>The reference mapping for the member.</returns>
 public virtual MemberReferenceMap References<TClassMap>(
     Expression<Func<TClass, object?>> expression, 
     params object[] constructorArgs) where TClassMap : ClassMap


This method returns a MemberReferenceMap.  You can use its Prefix(string? prefix = null, bool inherit = false) method to assign your MyC*_ prefixes.  Thus your class maps could look like:
class AMap : ClassMap<A>
{
    public AMap()
    {
        References<CMap>(m => m.MyC).Prefix("MyC_");
        Map(m => m.OtherStuff);
    }
}

class BMap : ClassMap<B>
{
    public BMap()
    {
        References<CMap>(m => m.MyC1).Prefix("MyC1_");
        References<CMap>(m => m.MyC2).Prefix("MyC2_");
    }
}

class CMap : ClassMap<C>
{
    public CMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.WeirdInt).Name("WeirdInt");
        Map(m => m.WeirdString).Name("WeirdString");
    }
}

Which will generate the following CSV for A:
MyC_WeirdInt,MyC_WeirdString,OtherStuff
1,1,101 

And for B:
MyC1_WeirdInt,MyC1_WeirdString,MyC2_WeirdInt,MyC2_WeirdString
101,101,201,201 

Notes:

The code comments state, surprisingly, that the References() method is for "internal use only" however the method is fully unit tested (e.g. here) so I think it is OK to use.

Demo fiddle here

Thanks!!! I'll try it when I have time!

By the way, I have some other questions, when I had this problem this time, I tried the whole reading through the official documentation, asked questions to the AI, tried searching, but nothing. When I next encounter a similar problem, how do I fix it? Do I just have to go on Stack Overflow and ask questions and pray that I'm lucky enough that a kind savior comes to save me? How did you know the answer to this? Is there something wrong with the way I'm solving the problem?

@狸子Neazle - AI is likely worthless for anything other than libraries with many thousands of public code samples.  I'd check the official docs, and it that doesn't work, check the obsolete API reference. It was removed and replaced with a "Coming soon..." page but the old API reference is partly available through the internet archive. Failing that search here for questions here with the [tag:csvhelper] tag.  Failing that ask here. Failing that ask on github.
